# convert tuple list of list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What's proper way to convert list of list of tuple to dataframe?
e.g.

```
data = [
[('A',1),('B',2)],
[('A',2),('B',3)],
[('A',3),('B',4)],
]
```

I would like to get a dataframe as below:

```
  A B
  1 2
  2 3
  3 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `list of dict`s from `list of tuple`s and then create dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(lst) for lst in data)
# Or
# df = pd.DataFrame(map(dict,data))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
```

Explanation:

```
>>> list(map(dict, data))
[{'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 4}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(map(dict, data))
```